# In App Purchase "sign in to itunes store" after [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver asking for App Store password on startup after in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988663/skpaymentqueue-addtransactionobserver-asking-for-app-store-password-on-startup-a)

I have a problem, when I loadStore in app purchase I add a transaction observer, the problem is that when I add the observer I get a message to sign in to the itunes store, to buy something, does it may be that last transactions didn't finished?

Comment: It is supposed to ask you for a login. So it is not a bug. It is proper behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm having the same problem... But I can tell you that it only happens on ONE of my iPads, and not the other.  (They were both 4.3.3).

> Sign in to the iTunes Store
>   If you have an Apple ID, sign in with it here.
>   AOL members can sign in using there AOL username and password.
>   [Environment Sandbox]
>   [Cancel]  [Buy]

Silly apple, how can I test my app if I'm logged into iTunes?

But even if I login (Buy), this dialog appears EVERYTIME launch my app and fetch my product description.  THEN, I see my sandbox login.

Tried a restore, and it disappeared for the first run.  Perplexing...

=====

LATER:
It seems that restoring the device (3 times) has fixed the problem.  I wish I had a more concrete answer for you.  But it worked for me.

=====

MUCH LATER:  Yup.  Signing-in every time when prompted by Apple did the trick.  I eventually caught up with my backlog of incomplete transactions.  (And deleting my old test accounts in iTunes seemed to be a faster way to accomplish the same thing.)

Comment: look, I found an answer to this, you probably created a lot of users and tried to test you in app purchase, and somehow you probably cancelled the purchase or stoped the inapp purchase process, so the device still remember the last transactions, you should enter all the accounts passwords and let the device finished the transactions, that is the only answer I got, just go with this silly thing and when this popup jumps enter the corrent password and click buy do this till you don't have any more, one thing more this done after you add transaction observer

Comment: I had the same problem.  The solution for me was to create a new sandbox user.  There must have been a number of transactions that were causing it to be unhappy, probably because I eg. quit the debugger before FinishTransaction was called.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, which was fixed by calling `finishTransaction:` on the payment queue. Without this the transaction persists like a lost phantom.

Comment: What do you mean calling finishTransaction: on payment queue? Which SKPaymentTransaction are you passing as argument on finishTransaction function? In my array of transactions there is no transaction to finish...