# When In-App Purchase testing keep getting asked for App Store password coming from background

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, in-app-purchase

I am testing In-App Purchases in Xcode.

I have set up a test account as per apple documentation. My problem is that every time I go into the background and then come back into my app I get prompted for my test App Store password. However, as far as I can see I am not calling any of my In-App Purchase functionality.

Is this a quirke of the testing environment?

I've tried re-specifying my original "proper" App Store userID/password in General settings but I still get prompted for my test App Store password on entering my app from the background again. Once I have put in the  password everything is OK until I enter from the background again and then if it doesn't ask me for it again.

I haven't included any code because as far as I can see none of my In-App Purchase code is being accessed when I get this behaviour

Comment: which iOS version are you running?

Comment: Are you properly closing you transactions by calling `finishTransaction:` in your `SKPaymentQueue`?

Comment: My iOS version is iOS 7.1.2

Comment: Good suggestion spassas. I will go and check it.

Comment: This should answer your question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988663/skpaymentqueue-addtransactionobserver-asking-for-app-store-password-on-startup-a