# Restore Purchase : Non-Consumable

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, restore

I have completed a small app where I have a non-consumable purchase option. It is on the App Store.

The purchase of the product runs OK. It's my Restore Purchase function that seems to do nothing.

I have added this code for the Restore Purchase `@IBAction`:

```
@IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: AnyObject) { 
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

But nothing happens when I hit the restore purchase button.

I think I have to add a function that checks if the restore was successful or not. Am planning to amend code to the following:

```
@IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: AnyObject) { 
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
    if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .Restored:
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
            break;

        case .Failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry", message: "Your purchase(s) could not be restored.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
        break;

        default:
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Will this do the trick?

I have been through every thread in relation to effecting Restore Purchase transactions, and my research has led me to the above. So I don't think this is a duplicate of a question, but perhaps may clarify how to successfully restore purchases for others facing my similar situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your codes looks pretty fine for the most part, although some parts seem to be from older tutorials . There is some changes you should make, one of them is that you need to call your unlockProduct function again.

This is the code I use (Swift 3).

```
/// Updated transactions
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
         switch transaction.transactionState {

        case .purchasing:
            // Transaction is being added to the server queue.

        case .purchased:
            // Transaction is in queue, user has been charged.  Client should complete the transaction.

            defer {
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }

            let productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier

            unlockProduct(withIdentifier: productIdentifier)

        case .failed:
            // Transaction was cancelled or failed before being added to the server queue.

            defer {
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }

            let errorCode = (transaction.error as? SKError)?.code

            if errorCode == .paymentCancelled {
                print("Transaction failed - user cancelled payment")
            } else if errorCode == .paymentNotAllowed { // Will show alert automatically
               print("Transaction failed - payments are not allowed")
            } else {
                print("Transaction failed - other error")
                // Show alert with localised error description 
            }

        case .restored:
            // Transaction was restored from user's purchase history.  Client should complete the transaction.

            defer {
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }

            if let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier {
                unlockProduct(withIdentifier: productIdentifier)
            }

        case .deferred:
            // The transaction is in the queue, but its final status is pending external action 
            // e.g family member approval (FamilySharing). 
            // DO NOT freeze up app. Treate as if transaction has not started yet.
        }
    }
}
```

Than use the delegate methods to show the restore alert

```
/// Restore finished
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    guard queue.transactions.count != 0 else {
        // showAlert that nothing restored
        return
    }

    // show restore successful alert 
}

/// Restore failed
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError) {

     /// handle the restore error if you need to. 
}
```

Unlock product is just a method I am sure you already have too.

```
  func unlockProduct(withIdentifier productIdentifier: String) {
       switch productIdentifier {
         /// unlock product for correct ID
     }
  }
```

As a side note, you should move this line

```
 SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
```

out of your restore and buy function and put it in viewDidLoad.

Apple recommends you add the transaction observer as soon as your app launches  and only remove it when your app is closed. A lot of tutorials unfortunately dont teach you this correctly. This way you unsure that any incomplete transactions e.g due to network error, will always resume correctly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html

In my real projects my code for IAPs is in a Singleton class so I would actually using delegation to forward the unlockProduct method to my class that handles gameData. I can than also make sure the observer is added at app launch.

Hope this helps

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding

Comment: As of Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2 this code has to be changed slightly because the error is handled in enums now. I will update my answer later. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156724/unresolved-identifier-skerrorpaymentcancelled

Comment: Thats superb! Very much obliged kind sir.

Comment: @crashoverride777 I have done everything as you asked. But still when i try to restore IAP nothing happens like nothing, no even a failure callback. 
Interestingly when i close the app the iTunes login prompt opens and ask me to login only after closing the app.

Comment: Hey, it's hard to say what your issue is without seeing code. Can you ask a question please with some code samples.

Comment: This answer was old. I just updated the code to Swift 3. If you still got issues post a question please.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to suss out, but the reason my StoreKit was not updatingTransactions and restoring the purchase was because of a broken Configuration setting in my app's Scheme.   When I set that to None, it worked!

In Xcode I went into Edit>Scheme (image1) clicked on the Run>Options tab and selected None for StoreKit Configuration (image2).  I also went on my physical device, and logged out of my personal Apple purchase account (Settings >Your Name/Pic at the Top > Media & Purchases > Sign Out) (image3). And finally, this step might not be critical, but I logged into my test sandbox account on my device at the bottom of the Settings>App Store menu(image4 and image5).  That is an account that I setup in developer.apple.com under test users.

[image: edit scheme]
[image: run options]
[image: purchases off]
[image: app store settings]
[image: test user sandbox login]