# Unresolved Identifier - SKErrorPaymentCancelled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, storekit

I updated to the latest version of Xcode 7.3 with the release of iOS 9.3 & OSX 10.11.4 (inclusive of Swift 2.2) yesterday.

When I build my app I get an error stating
`Use of unresolved identifier 'SKErrorPaymentCancelled'` which I use to check if the user has cancelled a payment. I don't do anything special with it, just log it (as seen below).

```
private func failedTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("failedTransaction...")
    if transaction.error!.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled {
        print("Transaction Cancelled: \(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else {
        print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

I can't find anything in the Swift 2.2 changelog that states anything within StoreKit was changed. This worked fine before I updated.

Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The constant `SKErrorPaymentCancelled` has been removed from the SDK as of iOS 9.3.  Instead, use the [`SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enumelt/SKErrorCode/c:@E@SKErrorCode@SKErrorPaymentCancelled) enum.

For more information, see the [StoreKit Changes for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/Swift/StoreKit.html) page of the [iOS 9.3 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/) and my canonical Q&A post [Use of unresolved identifier when using StoreKit constants with iOS 9.3/Xcode 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36157086/2415822).

Comment: Is there documentation of this somewhere that I missed? Did they move all of the StoreKit error constants to SKErrorCode?

Comment: @mattdonders Check out the StoreKit changelog for the iOS 9.3 SDK: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/Swift/StoreKit.html

Comment: Oh thanks, definitely missed that. One more question to follow up on this then (if you know).

What property of transaction can be checked against SKErrorCode? My previous code (fixed from above) is `transaction.error!.code == SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled` but now I get `Cannot convert value of type 'SKErrorCode' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Comment: @mattdonders Use `.rawValue` to get the `Int` value from the enum.

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much for your help. Will accept once time has passed.

Comment: @mattdonders thanks!  Glad I was able to help!  I created a general [canonical Q&A post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157086/2415822) for these issues, as I know more questions will come up.

Comment: This is great - thanks!

Just FYI, when comparing the error (not the code itself) you get the below compilation error in Xcode - `Binary Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSError' and 'SKErrorCode'` so it seems you may need to cast one.

Comment: @mattdonders something like this should work: `if transaction.error?.code == SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue { ... }`.

Comment: It's been updated to `SKError.paymentCancelled`