# Use of unresolved identifier when using StoreKit constants with iOS 9.3/Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, storekit, nserror

I get the error "Use of unresolved identifier" when trying to use one of these StoreKit constants:

```
SKErrorClientInvalid
SKErrorPaymentCancelled
SKErrorPaymentInvalid
SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed
SKErrorStoreProductNotAvailable
SKErrorUnknown
```

Your code may look like this:

```
if transaction.error!.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled {
    print("Transaction Cancelled: \(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

What changed?  Is there a new module I need to import?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of iOS 9.3 certain StoreKit constants have been removed from the SDK.  See [StoreKit Changes for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/Swift/StoreKit.html) for the full list of changes.

These constants have been replaced in favor of the [`SKErrorCode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Store_Kit_Errors) enum and associated values:

```
SKErrorCode.ClientInvalid
SKErrorCode.CloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed
SKErrorCode.CloudServicePermissionDenied
SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled
SKErrorCode.PaymentInvalid
SKErrorCode.PaymentNotAllowed
SKErrorCode.StoreProductNotAvailable
SKErrorCode.Unknown
```

You should check be checking your `transaction.error.code` with the enum's `rawValue`.  Example:

```
private func failedTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("failedTransaction...")
    if transaction.error?.code == SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue {
        print("Transaction Cancelled: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else {
        print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

You should be checking against these error codes rather than the legacy constants if creating a new application using StoreKit on iOS 9.3 and above.

Comment: "You should check be checking your transaction.error with one of these values" i don't think thats possible. SKErrorCode is not a NSError. Only .code against .rawValue works for me.

Comment: @AceGreen thanks I'll make an edit.  So this works for you?  `if transaction.error?.code == SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue { ... }`

Comment: I use a switch statement but yes .code against .rawValue works (See answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @JAL answer heres a switch variant

```
        switch (transaction.error!.code) {
        case SKErrorCode.Unknown.rawValue:
            print("Unknown error")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.ClientInvalid.rawValue:
            print("Client Not Allowed To issue Request")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue:
            print("User Cancelled Request")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentInvalid.rawValue:
            print("Purchase Identifier Invalid")
            break;
        case SKErrorCode.PaymentNotAllowed.rawValue:
            print("Device Not Allowed To Make Payment")
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. What solved it was prepending StoreKit to the SKError.

My switch looked something like this:

```
switch (transaction.error!.code) {
        case StoreKit.SKErrorCode.Unknown.rawValue:
            print("Unknown error")
            break;
}
```

No idea why.

Comment: What was the error you were getting when just referencing the `SKErrorCode` struct?  It sounds like you have a namespace collision.