# iOS prompts "Sign-In required to enable Touch ID" after successful in app purchase - why?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app in Testflight Beta currently which implements a recurring in-app-purchase.

I use [react-native-inapp-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils) to implement it. The app calls the `InAppUtils.loadProducts()` function, then in the success callback of that `InAppUtils.purchaseProduct()`.

All of this seems to be working, but the dialogs that iOS presents during the purchase flow is strange.

First of all, the iTunes login prompt is shown TWICE. This is apparently "normal" in Sandbox accounts.

But the thing that I don't understand is the Touch ID prompt that shows up after a successful transaction. I do have Touch ID enabled, but why am I asked to "enable" this after the purchase?

[image]

Comment: did you call the finishTransaction:transaction directive at the end of your flow?

Comment: @zoubida13 Yes, the library does that when the transaction is complete: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils/blob/master/InAppUtils/InAppUtils.m#L61

Comment: im experimenting same behavior but using xamarin. Wasn't happening before.

Comment: does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988663/skpaymentqueue-addtransactionobserver-asking-for-app-store-password-on-startup-a

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, and I have made sure to call finishTransaction for all 3 states as mentioned in other posts/answers. This only is occurring on devices with Touch ID. We have a test device without Touch and it only ever prompts a single time.

edit: I have a discussion started with Apple's dev support team to see what is up.