# Not getting expected delegate calls when trying to restore in-app purchases with StoreKit

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've read over a number of questions (with no consistent answers) on restoring IAPs in StoreKit API. The part that seems to be incredibly ambiguous - in a test/sandbox environment - is what happens when you restore.

When using this method:

```
@IBAction func restorePurchasesButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {        
   SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions(withApplicationUsername: productID)
}
```

I get no feedback other than a call to the

```
paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue)
```

function. Is there not a way to determine if the restore purchases was successful? I thought that the call would pass through this function:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
            //item already purchased
            print("Transaction successful...")
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
            print("Transaction failed...")
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .restored {
            print("Restored purchases...")
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not get called. If I try to make a purchase that has already been made against a product, the updatedTransactions func gets called, but only with a .purchased value.

I have read so many things about sandbox being weird and unpredictable. I have set up numerous verified sandbox accounts and none of them work as  expected.

Purchase functionality seems to work fine. If I purchase what has already been purchased, it gets restored with a notification. But, I can not call the restoreCompletedTransactions and figure out how to get any value - success or fail. What am I missing here? Is there a definitive answer or a workaround?

Comment: In theory it should go through the paymentQueue() function as you expect.  So... I don't know.  Are you dealing with more than one product?  I have a known working in-app-purchase module but it's only designed for one product -- an "app unlock."  I can share that code if you want.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated. This is a very simple single product scheme. To see something that is working would be very helpful. I’ve gone through more complex multi-IAP schemes but they don’t necessarily translate. Let me know what you need in order to share. Many thanks.

Comment: @BooberBunz if you can post it here, awesome. If easier, just send to code@talendia.com - again, many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/BooberBunz/In-app-purchases-on-IOS

Comment: @BooberBunz - worked great! I implemented this with a single Buy/Restore action and let the user decide what to do based on the selection from the single Buy/Restore/Cancel alert in your VC code. I think I expected StoreKit to provide some sort of callback if the user tries to restore purchase without having purchased already. I also couldn't find an elegant way to change the state of the action button in my VC so added a listener that works based on the value of an isPurchased global. I'm sure there is a better way. Will be improving. Approved in App Store. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good to hear!  I'm going to write it in answer form here, also, so other may see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following modular swift file, UnlockManager.swift in your app to implement in-app-purchases, although I can only guarantee it will work for a single non-consumable product, for example an unlock purchase... otherwise, you'll need to do some modification.

Anyway, here's the meat and potatoes:

UnlockManager.swift:

```
//  2019 Boober Bunz. No rights reserved.

import StoreKit

protocol UnlockManagerDelegate: class {
    func showUnlockPurchaseHasBeenRestoredAlert()
}

class UnlockManager : NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    // Only used in print debugging
    // let transactionStateStrings = ["purchasing","purchased","failed","restored","deferred"]
    
    weak var delegate: UnlockManagerDelegate?
    
    private let UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID = "your_product_ID_goes_here" // <------------------------------------ ***
    
    private var requestObject: SKProductsRequest?
    private var skProductObject: SKProduct?
    
    private var onlineAndReadyToPurchase = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init() //important that super.init() comes first
        attemptStoreKitRequest()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    deinit {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    }
    
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ STOREKIT CALLBACKS
    
    // SKProductsRequestDelegate response
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        
        if response.products.count > 0 {
            for product in response.products {
                if product.productIdentifier == UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID {
                    skProductObject = product
                    onlineAndReadyToPurchase = true
                    print("IAP - StoreKit server responded with correct product.  We are ready to purchase.")
                    return // success
                }
            }
        } else { // fail
            print("IAP MODULE - on initial request, StoreKit server responded, but \(UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID) not found.")
            print("IAP MODULE - Check for product ID mismatch.")
            print("IAP MODULE - We are not ready to purchase.\n")
        }
    }
    
    // SKProductsRequestDelegate response (fail)
    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("IAP MODULE - on initial request, StoreKit server responded with explicit error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    
    // SKPaymentTransactionObserver calls this
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                             updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        
        print("IAP MODULE - SKPaymentTransactionObserver called paymentQueue()...")
        
        //    print("Transaction Queue:")
        
        for transaction in transactions {
            //    print("\n PRODUCT ID: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
            //    print(" TRANS ID: \(transaction.transactionIdentifier)")
            //    print(" TRANS STATE: \(transactionStateStrings[transaction.transactionState.rawValue])")
            //    print(" TRANS DATE: \(transaction.transactionDate)")
            
            //    print("\nActions taken as a result of trans.state...")
            
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                
                if (transaction.payment.productIdentifier == UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID) {
                    print("IAP MODULE - successful purchase of \(UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID), so unlocking")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID)
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                }
                break
            case .restored:
                guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }
                if (productIdentifier == UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID) {
                    if !(appIsUnlocked()){
                        delegate?.showUnlockPurchaseHasBeenRestoredAlert()
                    }
                    print("IAP MODULE - previous purchase of \(UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID), so restoring/unlocking")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID)
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                }
                break
            case .failed:
                if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError?,
                    let localizedDescription = transaction.error?.localizedDescription,
                    transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
                    print("IAP MODULE - ... error in transaction \(transaction.transactionIdentifier ?? "no ID?") for product: \((transaction.payment.productIdentifier)): \(localizedDescription)")
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ PUBLIC ONLY METHODS
    public func purchaseApp() -> Bool {
        if !onlineAndReadyToPurchase {
            print("IAP MODULE - Purchase attempted but we are not ready!")
            return false
        }
        print("IAP MODULE - Buying \(skProductObject!.productIdentifier)...")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: skProductObject!)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        return true
    }
    
    public func restorePurchases() -> Bool {
        if !onlineAndReadyToPurchase {
            print("IAP MODULE - User attempted restore, but we are presumbly not online!")
            return false
        }
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        return true
    }
    
    public func appIsUnlocked() -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID)
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ PUBLIC AND INTERNAL METHODS
    
    // Presumably called on app start-up
    // AND (for good measure) when user is presented with purchase dialog
    public func attemptStoreKitRequest() {
        if !onlineAndReadyToPurchase {
            requestObject = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: [UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID])
            print("IAP MODULE - sending request to StoreKit server for product ID: \(UNLOCK_IAP_PRODUCT_ID)...")
            print("IAP MODULE - waiting for response...")
            requestObject?.delegate = self
            requestObject?.start()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I wanted to say thank you, I read lots of different ways but only yours works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Seems, there is an issue calling updatedTransactions when iOS version is less than 13.0
It works well from iOS 13.0 onwards.

[My work around for iOS versions below 13.0:
Showing message like: If the product is already purchased, tap on "Restore" button.
Because if we tap on Buy, it shows, "This In-App is already bought message", after tap on OK, it's not calling updatedTransactions method.]