# iOS Manage my Subscription with Sandbox Account

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, in-app-purchase, ios10

### Background

I have an application that supports in-app purchase with Apple subscription (in particular auto-renewable plans).

Using the WWDC 2016 slides material, in the **Manage Subscription** page, (inside iTunes & App Store -> View my Apple ID), we have this:

[image]

in which the user is allowed to change the current subscription plan (and also to cancel it). So far, so good.

### Case scenario

I would like to simulate the scenario of a user changing account (or cancelling the current subscription) from the Manage Subscriptions page.

### My issue (and possible solutions)

Thus, I am now facing the issue of testing the reported scenario.

It seems to conflict with Sandbox Account for testing purposes. In particular: if I try to login with the sandbox Apple ID into the iTunes Store & App Store page, I of course receive the message: *iTunes Account creation not allowed* (as reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266084/itunes-account-creation-not-allowed-when-trying-to-test-in-app-purchases)).

The most straight-forward solution seems the one reported in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289011/ios-sandbox-test-user-account-subscription-management) (shortly: let the subscription plan auto-renew for 5 times with 5 minutes period, after which we should receive the 21006 error). Anyway, I am not sure that it could be applied to this case, since it seems only including the *cancel my subscription* case.

Another thread comes directly from the apple forum ([this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14702)) but: (1) something is strange, i.e. the iTunes account creation not allowed error seems not to appear when logging into iTunes with sandbox accounts - while it happens to me systematically) and (2) even after logging in, the subscriptions are reported not to be shown.

I expect that everything works using a real Apple ID, but this is something I don't really want to do.

### Conclusion (?) and question

So, finally :), my question. Is there a way to test the reported case scenario (or an equivalent one) *without using a real apple ID*, thus without triggering a real transaction? I don't really want to believe that the current sandbox testing mechanism does not include it.

Thanks in avance to all!

Comment: I'd also love to know how that works... did you ever figure out the answer to your question?

Answer (score 8):

An iTunesConnect Sandbox test user account can test auto-renewing subscriptions but that account cannot login to iTunes and utilize the Manage Subscriptions.

### Only Option

The only option I have seen being utilized is to essentially get your app fully approved for the app store (do not auto-release). Once approved, use a promo code to download and live test the Manage Subscription scenarios.  If it all checks out, release the app. (I cant seem to find the link for this but will add it here if I come across it.)

### Other Notes Testing Auto-Renewing Subscriptions

> Duration times are shortened when test your auto-renewable subscriptions. Additionally, test subscriptions only auto-renew a maximum of **six times**.

[Reference Link](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d%22Reference%20Link%22)
 ~*Emphasis is mine*

- 1 week   = 3 minutes
- 1 month  = 5 minutes
- 2 months = 10 minutes
- 3 months = 15 minutes
- 6 months = 30 minutes
- 1 year = 1 hour

This thread has a response posted from an Apple Developer in regards to this situation. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289011/ios-sandbox-test-user-account-subscription-management)